# Recently Deployed My App - Some Users Cannot Run Now From Older Devices (64 bit issue)

Tags: ios, xcode, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I recently put out a large update for my app and now my old iPhone 5 users cannot run it. I wanted to get some information to see if there was anything I can do, or if they just have to upgrade their phones.

My understanding is that a few years ago, Apple started to make those pop-ups for people who were running 32-bit applications telling them that their device may be slowed down running this app until the developer updates.

So I took this as an opportunity to make sure my app was 64 bit. I'm not entirely sure what I did (I don't frankly remember it's been a while) but now my older users are out of luck it would appear.

Is there a way to make my app run both 32 bit and 64 bit, or is this a bad idea / I do not want to do that?

Curious what options I have on the table.

Thanks!

Comment: Your iPhone5 user should still be able to use your app, they just cant update to iOS11 which only support 64-bit, but your app should be support both 32 and 64 bit arch, unless you deleted some value on valid architecture in your build settings

Comment: Interesting, ok maybe there is another reason for them crashing then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app should include 32 bit symbols in addition to 64 bit symbols. You might have removed 32 bit symbols from your app. That causes your app to crash on 32 bit devices.

To do that, set your Architecture in your target's build settings to $(ARCHS_STANDARD). ARCHS_STANDARD includes both arm64 and armv7 architectures.

[image]

Comment: it wouldn't have to do with the base sdk being 11 right? Like what you have above? I have what you have above (arm65 armv7 and armv7s) so therefore should be good right?

Comment: Yes. Architecture and base sdk are two different things. To support 32bit and 64bit architectures, Architecture and Valid Architectures settings should include them.

Comment: I didn't download the simulators before I did an archive (iPhone 5 simulator, for example, as well as iOS 10.1). This was because Xcode (the latest version) doesn't include them anymore. So I just downloaded them now in Xcode and ran it on a 5 simulator and it worked. Should I have done that earlier when I released the app, or is that not relevant? If not, any other ideas you can think of? I seem to have what you had in the above screen shot.. Not sure what else it could be :(